# PHP Include Absolute/Relative Paths CSS

Tags: php

My PHP files within folders are not rendering my default CSS files.

I have a "document-head.php" file that contains:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css"/>
```

Within each file I include this 'document-head.php';

For example, the directory I have is:

```
index.php
|__ assets
    |__ css
        |__ main.css
|__ includes

    |__ document-head.php

|__ components
    |__ secondary.php

|__ partials
```

Within "components/secondary.php" contains

```
 <?php include('../_includes/document_head.php'); ?>
```

And within "index.php" contains:

```
<?php include('_includes/document_head.php'); ?>
```

How do I make sure that files within folders that include this "document_head.php" always render CSS/JS files?

Edit:
The reason I can't use absolute URL's is that one of the developers configured a script that allows me to upload my application to an FTP where I can name a new folder. For example, if all my files are in "secret-app", in the terminal I can publish my app to an FTP with the new folder "test-app" and it will create "mydomain.com/test-app/secret-app". (It's a ghetto system, but it's useful for my particular needs.)

Comment: Is it a problem to set the domainname in the href?

Comment: Use a setting / config file to set the absolute path prefix, and load the config file in every php ( normally I call the file `require_once.php` )

Comment: Why can you not use absolute URLs? `/assets/css/main.css`?

Comment: The reason I can't use absolute URL's is that one of the developers configured a script that allows me to upload my application to an FTP where I can name the new folder. For example, if all my files are in "secret-app", in the terminal I can publish my app with the new folder "test-app" and it will load "mydomain.com/test-app/secret-app". (It's a ghetto system, but it's useful for my particular needs.

Comment: You need to figure out the base url then, this is possible via PHP ($_SERVER variables). In the HTML you could use absolute url's, making use of the base tag in the head of your document (containing the base url to your app, mydomain.com/test-app/secret-app/) - see  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try change to an absolute href url like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/yourApp/assets/css/main.css"/>
```

If you're using a framework, you will have several ways to get your **base_url**.

Comment: Edited for why I can't use absolute paths.

Comment: any way you can get the  base_url using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

Comment: When I test locally, it is "localhost" but when I upload to my server it is "mydomain"

Comment: If you put only / you don't need to specify your local or remote domain, only you need to have the same path in both servers to works.

Answer (score 0):

if this stylesheet is within the document_head.php

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css"/>
```

then try this :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css"/>
```

sorry for my grammar :D